# python: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I create a convolutional neural network using sensor data. Now i want to save the model and weights. But there is a question generate when i running the code. I have searched the blog and document but have no idea. I hope someone can help me.
the wrong is :

```
TypeError                                 

    201 plt.savefig('cmatrix.png')
    202 #plt.show();
--> 203 Model.save("model.h5")
    204 Model.save_weights("model_weights")
    TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'
```

the dataset is [enter link description here](https://github.com/ohdoughnut/dataset/blob/master/ab.7z). the code is as follow:

```
import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import timing
    from keras.layers import Input,Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D,Flatten
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras import backend as K
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    from keras.models import Sequential# 导入Sequential
    from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
    from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
    import os
    from keras.layers import Dropout
    from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
    import tensorflow as tf
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,  cross_val_score
    from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, StratifiedKFold
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    from sklearn import metrics
    import time
    from scipy import stats
    from keras import optimizers
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from keras import regularizers
    import keras
    from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
    config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
    time1 = time.time()
    class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
            self.losses = {'batch':[], 'epoch':[]}
            self.accuracy = {'batch':[], 'epoch':[]}
            self.val_loss = {'batch':[], 'epoch':[]}
            self.val_acc = {'batch':[], 'epoch':[]}

        def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            self.losses['batch'].append(logs.get('loss'))
            self.accuracy['batch'].append(logs.get('acc'))
            self.val_loss['batch'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))
            self.val_acc['batch'].append(logs.get('val_acc'))

        def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            self.losses['epoch'].append(logs.get('loss'))
            self.accuracy['epoch'].append(logs.get('acc'))
            self.val_loss['epoch'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))
            self.val_acc['epoch'].append(logs.get('val_acc'))

        def loss_plot(self, loss_type):
            iters = range(len(self.losses[loss_type]))
            plt.figure()
            # acc
            plt.plot(iters, self.accuracy[loss_type], 'r', label='train acc')
            # loss
            plt.plot(iters, self.losses[loss_type], 'g', label='train loss')
            if loss_type == 'epoch':
                # val_acc
                plt.plot(iters, self.val_acc[loss_type], 'b', label='val acc')
                # val_loss
                plt.plot(iters, self.val_loss[loss_type], 'k', label='val loss')
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.xlabel(loss_type)
            plt.ylabel('acc-loss')
            plt.legend(loc="center")
            plt.show()
            #plt.savefig('common.png')


    #dataset
    RANDOM_SEED = 42
    def read_data(file_path):
        column_names = ['user-id', 'activity', 'timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
        m = pd.read_csv(file_path,names=column_names, header=None,sep=',')
        return m
    def feature_normalize(dataset):
        mu = np.mean(dataset,axis=0)
        sigma = np.std(dataset,axis=0)
        return (dataset-mu)/sigma

    dataset1 = read_data('ab.txt')
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset1)
    dataset['x-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['x-axis'])
    dataset['y-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['y-axis'])
    dataset['z-axis'] = feature_normalize(dataset['z-axis'])

    N_TIME_STEPS = 200
    N_FEATURES = 3
    step = 200
    segments = []
    labels = []
    for i in range(0, len(dataset) - N_TIME_STEPS, step):
        xs = dataset['x-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
        ys = dataset['y-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
        zs = dataset['z-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
        label = stats.mode(dataset['activity'][i: i + N_TIME_STEPS])[0][0]
        segments.append([xs, ys, zs])
        labels.append(label)
    print("reduced size of data", np.array(segments).shape)
    reshaped_segments = np.asarray(segments,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,1, N_TIME_STEPS, 3)
    print("Reshape the segments", np.array(reshaped_segments).shape)
    #x_train1, x_val_test, y_train1, y_val_test = train_test_split(reshaped_segments, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

    batch_size = 128
    num_classes =6

    def create_model():
        input_shape = Input(shape=(1,200,3))
        #x = Conv2D(7, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='valid')(input_shape)
        #x1 = keras.layers.concatenate([input_shape, x], axis=-1)

        x = Conv2D(50, kernel_size=(1, 7),padding='valid',
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
        kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(0.0015),name='conv1')(input_shape)


        x = keras.layers.core.Activation('relu',name='act1')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2),name='maxpool1')(x)
        x = Conv2D(50, kernel_size=(1, 7),padding='valid',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
               kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0015),name='conv2')(x)
        x = keras.layers.core.Activation('relu',name='act2')(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2),name='maxpool2')(x)

        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dropout(0.9)(x)
        output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',name='dense1')(x)
        model = Model(inputs=input_shape,outputs=output)
        model.summary()

        sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.005,decay=1e-6,momentum=0.9,nesterov=True)
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,                        
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
    history = LossHistory()
    epochs = 4000

    #setting learning rate
    def scheduler(epoch):
        if epoch > 0.75 * epochs:
            lr = 0.0005
        elif epoch > 0.25 * epochs:
            lr = 0.001
        else:
            lr = 0.005
        return lr

    scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
    estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model)

    scores = []
    confusions = []   #list of confusion matrix
    sign = ['DOWNSTAIRS','JOGGING','SITTING','STANDING','UPSTAIRS','WALKING']
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder_y = encoder.fit_transform(labels)

    train_labels = to_categorical(encoder_y,num_classes=None)

    kfold = StratifiedKFold(labels,n_folds=10,shuffle=True,random_state=42)
    for train_index,test_index in kfold:
        x_train, x_test = reshaped_segments[train_index], reshaped_segments[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = train_labels[train_index], train_labels[test_index]
        estimator.fit(x_train,y_train,callbacks=[scheduler,history],epochs=2,batch_size=128,verbose=0)
        scores.append(estimator.score(x_test,y_test))
        pred_test = estimator.predict(x_test)  
        confusions.append(metrics.confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_test,axis=1),pred_test))

    matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]

    for i in np.arange(3):
        for j in np.arange(6):
            for k in np.arange(6):
                matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] + confusions[i][j][k]   

    #Model.save("model.h5")
    #Model.save_weights("model_weights")    
    print('score:',scores)
    scores = np.mean(scores)
    print('mean:',scores)

    time2 = time.time()
    time3 = time2-time1
    print(time3)

    plt.figure(figsize=(16,14))     
    sns.heatmap(matrix, xticklabels=sign, yticklabels=sign, annot=True, fmt="d");
    plt.title("CONFUSION MATRIX : ")
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.savefig('cmatrix.png')
    #plt.show();
    Model.save("model.h5")
    Model.save_weights("model_weights")
```

Comment: You probably want to call `.save` on an *instance* of `Model`, not on the class `Model`. I.e. `Model().save('foo')` will do, `Model.save('foo')` does not.

Comment: If i use Model().save('foo'), new mistake emerged. TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'inputs' and 'outputs'

Comment: Yeah, well, the model constructor wants some of its own arguments, yes. Somewhere you are doing `model = Model(...)`. You'll want to do `model.save(...)` then on that instance.

Comment: I have tried this situation, but there are still some problems. NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Comment: @ohdoughnut: yes, you do need to work through a tutorial on creating and saving a model.  In this case, your *next* problem is that you create the model within a subroutine, return the object to the calling routine -- which then passes the handle in-line to another function and otherwise throws away the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer. I want to call the created model, but the model is defined in the create_model() function. So i should define the model as global, then use model.save() to save model.

Comment: Or you could just return the model from the function. Cleaner code!